# Qt deploying qgif4.dll plugin for QMovie

Tags: qt, deployment, gif

I'm having problems with deploying an application on Windows that displays an animated gif. For this purpose I use a QMovie and it works fine if I launch it from QtCreator. I gathered the files that are needed to run the application, and I can launch it just fine, but the gif won't show up.

[I read this page](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/deployment-windows.html) and came to the conclusion that I need to add the qgif4.dll plugin which is located in `qt/bin/plugins/imageformats`. I tried copying it into a `plugins` folder next to the application, also `plugins/imageformats`, but it still doesn't work. I also tried to

`QApplication::addLibraryPath(QDir::currentPath());`

and copy the qgif4.dll file next to my executable - without any success. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put it in ./imageformats, relative to the executable.